# Calculus - Continuous Function Proof Help

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, solution-verification

Regarding this question:

Let $f$ be function that is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Suppose that $f(x)>0$ for every $x \in [0,1]$.

Then there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $f(x)>\varepsilon$ for every $x \in [0,1]$.

--

So I want to say: because $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, and $f(x)>0$ for every $x \in [0,1]$, so $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)>0$. So $f(0)f(1)>0$.

From the intermediate value theorem, there is NO such a point $c \in R$ that $0<c<1$ such that $f(c)=0$.

From here I need some hint to continue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $[0,1]$ is compact, so $f$ has a $\min$ and this must be $>0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is immediate using the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: Oh I see, so because $f$ has Max & Min, the Minimum can't be $0$ or below it, so there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>\varepsilon$?

Comment: Exactly that!!!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! :)

Comment: I would say there's an $m>0$ so that $f(x)\ge m$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Awesome, nice!!